# Linq to Sql Force Order By

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

Is there a way in Linq to Sql (.net 3.5) to specify that when you get the children of a particular record, to force the list of children to come back in a specific order?

For example, I have a list that has a "DisplayOrder" on it.  When I ask my parent record/object for it's property that returns to me this list, I want Linq to Sql to retrieve for me the records, but ordered by "DisplayOrder".

Is it possible to do this without always writing something like:

```
MyObject.Children.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder);
```

An idea off the top of my head is to create a partial class for my object and add an "OrderedChildren" property that encapsulates this call.  Wondering though, if there isn't something I can specify in the dbml to force this.

Answer (score 4):

The [DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534221.aspx) method will filter all objects for a certain relationship. This includes `Where()`, `OrderBy()`, `ThenBy()`, `OrderByDescending()`, `ThenByDescending()`, and `Take()`.

You can use this within a partial method in your `DataContext` like the following:

```
partial class ExampleDataContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
        dlo.AssociateWith<MyObject>(i => i.Children.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder));
        LoadOptions = dlo;
    }
}
```

You'll want to make sure the `LoadOptions` are never overwritten prior to running other queries.

Comment: Was asking if there is a way I can manipulate the dbml to perform this action every time I load the child records for "MyObject".  Sort of setting the default loading sort order.

Comment: This may not be directly within the dbml, but it should take care of your issue now. There may be a way of making sure this only happens when querying the `MyObjects` table, but I haven't found it yet.